# R, dplyr: Looping over a subset of columns by name and applying mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

My current setup uses R 3.4.2 and tidyverse 1.1.1.

My aim is to transform data in the manner of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33990970) but to do so in a way that is extensible, so that I can easily change the set of variables that I wish to perform this operation with.

For the sake of definiteness, let us take the following data:

```
library(tidyverse)

df = tibble(
  id = seq(1,8),
  hair.colour = c("red", "blonde", "brown", "black", "red", "blonde", "brown", "black"),
  eye.colour = c("blue", "brown", "blue", "brown", "blue", "brown", "blue", "brown"),
  gender = c("male", "male", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female",
             "female"))
```

Code such as this works as desired:

```
df2 = df %>%
  mutate(value = 1,
         hair.colour = paste("hair.colour", hair.colour, sep = ".")) %>%
  spread(hair.colour, value, fill = 0)
```

Naively attempting to wrap this in a loop, e.g.

```
factors = c("hair.colour", "eye.colour", "gender")
for (factor in factors) {
    df = df %>%
        mutate(value = 1, factor = paste(toString(factor), factor, sep = ".")) %>%
        spread(factor, value, fill = 0)
}
```

does not work. I imagine there's a clever way using quo(), !!, etc., but I'm new to R, and my searches have yielded nothing that I can use.

Does anyone have any advice, both within the tidyverse (especially if it finds a way to use the same code as in the second block) and outside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
factors = c("hair.colour", "eye.colour", "gender")
for (factor in factors) {
  df = df %>%
    mutate(value = 1, x = paste(factor,.[[factor]], sep = ".")) %>%
    select_(paste0("-",factor)) %>%
    spread(x, "value", fill = 0)
}
```

The dot `.` is a shortcut for the left hand side when using pipes, so when typing `.[[factor]]` I could have written `df[[factor]]` just the same, so i'm pasting the value of your factor string to the value of the relevant column.

`select_` is a variant of `select` using standard evaluation (basically you feed it strings), dplyr and tidyr functions usually have one. for more: `?select_`

result:

```
# # A tibble: 8 x 9
#      id hair.colour.black hair.colour.blonde hair.colour.brown hair.colour.red eye.colour.blue eye.colour.brown gender.female gender.male
# * <int>             <dbl>              <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>            <dbl>         <dbl>       <dbl>
# 1     1                 0                  0                 0               1               1                0             0           1
# 2     2                 0                  1                 0               0               0                1             0           1
# 3     3                 0                  0                 1               0               1                0             0           1
# 4     4                 1                  0                 0               0               0                1             0           1
# 5     5                 0                  0                 0               1               1                0             1           0
# 6     6                 0                  1                 0               0               0                1             1           0
# 7     7                 0                  0                 1               0               1                0             1           0
# 8     8                 1                  0                 0               0               0                1             1           0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer—it certainly works! Is there any chance you could explain what (1) ".[[factor]]" does, and (2) what the select_ variant of select does? (I'm sorry that I'm so clueless; it's hard to search for these things.)

Comment: no problem R is confusing to start with, and you're not starting with easy stuff :). See updated answer.

Comment: @docbiz You hay have seen that `select_` and other SE versions of verbs have been deprecated.  It still works for now, but FYI a common alternative is to use `select` with the helper function `one_of`.  In your case, `select( -one_of(factor) )`.

Answer (score 0):

Since, as @aosmith pointed out, `select_` is deprecated and you might want to have a more flexible solution, you might try

```
df %>% 
  # make data long
  gather(key = key, value = value, -id) %>% 
  # unite columns
  unite(col = new_key, key, value, sep = ".") %>% 
  # add column with 1 for indication when back to wide
  mutate(new_value = 1,
         # this is only needed if you want to keep the order of the variables:
         new_key = factor(new_key, levels = unique(new_key))) %>% 
  # transform back to wide, fill NAs with 0
  spread(key = new_key, value = new_value, fill = 0)
```