# Factors in many columns to boolean convert

Tags: r

My question is a little like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33990760/converting-factors-to-binary-in-r) but the problem with the structure of data is different:

Sample data:

```
df  <-data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), stock_1 = c("Google","Microsoft","Yahoo"), stock_2 = c("Yahoo","Google","NA"))
```

and I would like to convert to this:

```
df  <-data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), Google = c(1,1,0), Microsoft = c(0,1,0), Yahoo= c(1,0,1))
```

I tried to use `sapply()` but from the answer to the linked question it is only for one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a way to do it with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
dcast(melt(df, id = 'id')[value != 'NA'],
      id ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
#    id Google Microsoft Yahoo
# 1:  1      1         0     1
# 2:  2      1         1     0
# 3:  3      0         0     1
```

`fill = 0` is unnecessary, and to tolerate duplicates, we can try:

```
dcast(melt(df, id = 'id')[value != 'NA'],
      id ~ value, fun.aggregate = function(x){ 1 * (length(x) != 0)})
```

---

2017-01-01

As mentationed by Uwe, we can removed from `NA`s from the molten data by setting `na.rm = TRUE` if it is not hard coded as a string (`"NA"`), the commands finally looks this:

```
dcast(melt(df, id = 'id', na.rm = TRUE), id ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
# or
dcast(melt(df, id = 'id', na.rm = TRUE),
      id ~ value, fun.aggregate = function(x){ 1 * (length(x) != 0)})
```

Comment: In order to remove `NA` values from the molten data you can call `melt()` with the parameter `na.rm = TRUE` instead of the subsequent  `[value != 'NA']`.

Comment: @Uwe, thanks for the nice comment. The Problem with OP's code is that the NA is coded as a string and `na.rm` does not work. Anyway, I edited the answer to reflect your suggesstion because it should be a more general case. :)

Answer (score 2):

We can also do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
   gather(key, val, -id) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(val)) %>% 
   mutate(ind = 1)  %>%
   select(-key) %>% 
   spread(val, ind, fill = 0)
```

NOTE: It is better to use `NA` instead of `"NA"` as we can take care of NA with `is.na` or `na.omit` or `complete.cases`