# Binary columns from text values

Tags: r, data.table

example data:

```
df_stock2 <-data.frame(url= c("https://www.example.com/test","https://www.example2.com/test","https://www.example3.com/test"), stock_yes_01 = c("Google","Microsoft","Yahoo"), stock_yes_02 = c("Yahoo","Google",NA))
```

I try to reproduce the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47909186/8935521):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df_stock2 )
df_stock3 <- dcast(melt(df_stock2 , url = 'url')[value != 'NA'],
      url ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
```

However it doesn't seam to work as expected.

Any idea why this is not working or what I have to change?

the error I receive:

```
> setDT(df_stock2)
    Warning message:
    In melt.data.table(df_stock2, url = "url") :
      To be consistent with reshape2's melt, id.vars and measure.vars are internally guessed when both are 'NULL'. All non-numeric/integer/logical type columns are conisdered id.vars, which in this case are columns [url, stock_yes_01, stock_yes_02, stock_yes_03, ...]. Consider providing at least one of 'id' or 'measure' vars in future.
df_stock3 <- dcast(melt(df_stock2, url = 'url')[value != 'NA'],
    +       url() ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
    Error in url() : argument "description" is missing, with no default
    In addition: Warning message:
    In melt.data.table(df_stock2, url = "url") :
      To be consistent with reshape2's melt, id.vars and measure.vars are internally guessed when both are 'NULL'. All non-numeric/integer/logical type columns are conisdered id.vars, which in this case are columns [url, stock_yes_01, stock_yes_02, stock_yes_03, ...]. Consider providing at least one of 'id' or 'measure' vars in future.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your call to `melt`. You've rename the argument `id` to `url`, and that of course does not work. The `id` argument tells the `melt` function, which variables should be used to identify observations. If you don't specify it, then `melt` will try to guess and take any non-numeric (or integer or logical) variables to be the id variables. That's what the warning was all about. The error is then caused by there not being any column named `id` after melting the data.

So just leave the `id` argument named correctly, and it works:

```
df_stock3 <- dcast(melt(df_stock2 , id = 'url')[value != 'NA'],
               url ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)
```

Comment: I would like to suggest a minor improvement. `melt()` has a parameter `na.rm` which can be used to remove `NA` values from the molten data. So,  `[value != 'NA']` can be saved by `df_stock3 <- dcast(melt(df_stock2 , id = 'url', na.rm = TRUE),
                   url ~ value, fun.aggregate = length)`